# AngularJS $resource multiple wildcards

Tags: angularjs, resources

Say I need to call `/calendar/day/month/year` to get my calendar for the day, but once I have the calendar, I'd like to only make a PUT request to `/calendar/id`. How can I accomplish this with one `$resource`? How can I create multiple URLs depending on the call method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the URL on `action` level:

```
app.factory('Calendar', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('/calendar', {}, {
    query: { 
      method: 'GET', 
      url: '/calendar/:day/:month/:year', 
      params: { 
        day: '@day', month: '@month', year: '@year' 
      } 
    },
    save: { 
      method: 'PUT', 
      url: '/calendar/:id', 
      params: { 
        id: '@id' 
      } 
    }
  });
});
```